# What's the penalty fee for rescheduling a flight on Garuda Airlines after buying the ticket?

Tags: fees-and-charges, itineraries, bali, garuda

What's the penalty fee for rescheduling a flight on Garuda Airlines after buying the ticket? I'm planning to buy a round-trip Seoul-Bali (DPS) with a planned departure in early May, but anticipate the possibility of having to reschedule the return flight back to Seoul.

Comment: This may depend on the type of ticket purchased, so there probably isn't a single answer.  You should see the change fee disclosed at some point along the way to booking the ticket.